# Image/graphics treatment with ps2pdf vs. Acrobat Distiller : can both achieve the same quality?

Tags: graphics, ps2pdf, acrobat

Hundreds of images are included in my free physics textbook. I use the `.dvi` -> `.ps` -> `.pdf` route and have all the images stored as `.eps` files. About two thirds contain `.jpg` files, sometimes `.png`, whereas the remaining third contains postscript illustrations.

When I use Adobe Acrobat Distiller,

[A] the General Tab allows to specify a dpi resolution. This should be similar to the `-r` option of ps2pdf.

[B] the PDF Settings Tab allows to specify the following about figures:

(1) How the images are treated: there is a setting about Sampling (allowing "Average Downsampling", or "Bicubic downsampling", or "subsampling") separately for colour, grayscale and monochrome images. The resolution, the compression (JPEG or ZIP or none) and the image quality can also be set separately.

(2) Color Settings: Setting File, Color Management Policy (e.g. "leave color unchanged", document rendering intent "relative colorimetric"), Device-Dependent Data ("preserve under color removal and black generation") etc.

(3) Advanced Settings: e.g., "saving PDF settings in the pdf file", "preserve overprint settings", and much more.

Now the question: can ps2pdf do the same as Distiller? If not, what is the best way to get results as similar to Distiller as possible? I usually produce a pdf version for the free web edition (with embedded films) and a separate pdf for the print edition (high quality printing). The used settings differ.

The man page of ps2pdf and of gs does not seem to provide any information. Any help on how to proceed will be greatly appreciated! I will add all information I receive below. I use texlive 2014. (There is no need to mention pdfopt or qpdf for web optimizing/linearizing.)

Comment: It seems that the use of -dDownsampleMonoImages=false -dDownsampleGrayImages=false -dDownsampleColorImages=false is a partial answer.

Comment: Most of the question is answered on the page http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.14/Ps2pdf.htm#Options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, every single point raised above is answered on the ghostscript ps2pdf page found at  [ghostscript.com/doc/9.14/Ps2pdf.htm#Options](http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.14/Ps2pdf.htm#Options) .

The pages answers [A], [B] (1), (2) and (3).

The only thing I am not sure about is the saving of settings inside the pdf.